# calling a webservice and deserializing soap without a wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a vendor who doesn't seem to have a wsdl or is unwilling or doesn't know how to provide it. They have a number of web services (technically they are JSPs that return soap messages) and I need to use about 10-15 of these to get my stuff done.

Since there isn't a WSDL, I can't use the 'add web reference' functionality to generate proxy classes and such. I've gotten around this by using `WebClient` to make the calls and return the response as a string, but now I need to deserialize the response into client classes.

I've already made c# classes to match the xml that's returned, but I'm not sure how to deserialize from SOAP since there's so much xml noise. I could strip the SOAP envelope tags and then use the XML serializer to deserialize to a `List<SomeType>`, but that seems really dirty. Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i published an article detailing on how to deserialize a complex xml.

here is the link : http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/06/30/how-to-serializedeserialize-complex-xml-in-asp-net-c/

hope it helps

Comment: this worked. I had to strip out the soap headers as well, but attributes allowed me to deserialize the xml properly

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SoapFormatter.Deserialize() for deserializing the response. If so, this would be helpful.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.deserialize(v=vs.71).aspx